# Three.JS path across a plane

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a really simple Three.js scene: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/paulsidebottom/aQEdH/)

By supplying a series of vectors from 2D space (plotted from the camera view 0, 0, 200) e.g. `{from:{x,:0, y:10}, to:{x:50,y:50}}` I would like to be able to draw a path across the face of the plane object much like the following example image depicts:

[image]

I am fairly new to Three.JS/ 3D in general and have looked at Vector3 and the path object but admit I'm a little stuck on where to begin - can anyone offer any suggestions or ideally a simple update to the JSFiddle I posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated your JSFiddle to do what you wanted (I think): http://jsfiddle.net/evgeni_popov/uBQnS/3/

The path is in the `path` variable. The lines are drawn with Z=1 so that they are not stuck in the plane, which is at Z=0.

I have changed your `MeshLamberMaterial` to `MeshBasicMaterial` so that we can see the lines better.

Comment: Sorry, one other related question: if I want to draw the line as a 3D path, is it a case of extruding the 2D line? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a 3D path ? You mean carving a path in the plane ? Then it is a lot more complicated, as you would have first to create a  box and not a plane (because a plane has no thickness), and then use CSG to carve the path in this box (which would also mean that your path should be constructed with boxes and not lines anymore). At least that would be a way to do it... There's a CSG lib for three js but I have never used it myself: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have figured it out now. I wanted the red path in the diagram above or the blue line in your example to be a 3D object.